# In gradle tasks of type Exec, why do commandLine and executable behave differently?

Tags: gradle

Does anyone know why in tasks of type `Exec` `commandline` and `executable` behave differently in terms of inheriting environment vars?

For example, I cannot run this Task because Gradle fails to find ruby from my environment:

```groovy
task checkRubyVersionCommandLine(type: Exec) {
   commandLine 'ruby -v'
}
```

Yet this works fine:

```groovy
task checkRubyVersionExecute(type: Exec) {
    executable = 'ruby' 
    args = ['-v']
}
```

What is `commandLine` for, or how can I get it to pick up the variables from the shell it is executed from? Why does `executable` just work?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When using the `commandLine`, you need to split the string on spaces, else the executable becomes `ruby -v`, instead of `ruby`.

So try this instead:

```groovy
task checkRubyVersionExecute(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'ruby', '-v'
}
```

See the code [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/process/internal/DefaultExecHandleBuilder.java) to see how the Exec task handles this.