# Cannot execute a shell script from gradle file

Tags: android, bash, android-studio, gradle, teamcity

I am using TeamCity as my CI server. I have a `build.gradle` file for an android project which contains

```
android{project.afterEvaluate{
task packDex(type:Exec)  {
    ....
    commandLine './script.sh'
    .....
}
}
```

On building my project I am getting a `org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException` error. How can I solve this. It is building in Android Studio but not in TeamCity. I am using gradle wrapper to build my project.Please help me out.

**EDIT:**

My simple doubt is whether the command `commandLine './script.sh'` is correct to start a shell script from a `build.gradle` file.I am using `Mac` as my server and using `gradle 1.0.0`

Comment: Any further details on the mentioned exception? The info you provided is quite useless.

Comment: @Opal `A problem occurred starting process 'command './script.sh ''` The error is only this much. Even I do not have much information

Comment: Try to run build with `-d` and `-s` switches to get more info. Basically, the configuration is ok. Does `script.sh` has `+x` mode set?

Comment: @Opal: `##teamcity[buildProblem identity='1510845881' description='Execution failed for task |':CustomClientLib:packDex|'. org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process |'command |'script.sh start|'|'' type='gradleBuildProblem']`. Mode is changed using a buildstep inTeamCity

Comment: I'm sorry this log extract is not telling anything :/

Comment: @Opal: Ya..I know that..that's my problem too...anyway thanks for your time

Comment: Have you tried `-s` along with `-d`?

Comment: Is ./script.sh executable? Are you setting executable "bash" or executable "sh" within the task just before the commandLine xxxxx ? Other thing, you are using Gradle 1.0.0? I would recommend, using greater than 1.6 atleast to the latest.

Comment: One other point to note is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776431/in-gradle-tasks-of-type-exec-why-do-commandline-and-executable-behave-different, you can also try: commandLine "bash", "./script.sh" as commandLine is a list, and every argument becomes a separate element of that list. Use bash or sh whatever you want.

Comment: @Opal:  I managed to work it out on my own...Thanks for your time..Answer is posted below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to work this one out myself.Just use the following piece of code.

```
android{project.afterEvaluate{
task packDex(type:Exec)  {
....
commandLine 'sh', './myScript.sh'
.....
}
}
```